# How can i restart the page, if the user closes an annoucment?

Tags: javascript

I've tried to implement the function, that if someone closes an specific annoucment that it automatically refreshes the site.

Here is the code which I have tried to solve it:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const closeButton = document.querySelector('name of annoucment');
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Button clicked');
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

The problem is, that sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes it doesnt work at all. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `const closeButton = document.querySelector('name of annoucment');`  name of annoucment? I'm assuming that's just there on the question but what do you really put in your querySelector?

Comment: Out of interest - why does it need to refresh the site?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the beforeunload event to reload the page when the announcement is closed, like this:

In this code, we add an event listener to the window object for the beforeunload event, which is fired when the page is about to be unloaded, such as when the user closes the announcement. We also declare a flag called announcementClosed and set it to false.

When the close button is clicked, we set the announcementClosed flag to true.

In the beforeunload event listener, we check if the announcementClosed flag is true. If it is, we reload the page. By using the beforeunload event, we can ensure that the event listener is always attached correctly, and that the page is reliably reloaded when the announcement is closed.

MDN Web Docs: beforeunload event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

```js
let announcementClosed = false;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const closeButton = document.querySelector('#closeButton');
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Button clicked');
    announcementClosed = true;
  });
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  if (announcementClosed) {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.reload();
  }
});
```